# Making a Minute Rate Metric in Netflix Servo

Tags: java, metrics, netflix, servo

I want to convert the StepCounter from doing the rates based on seconds to rate per minute (we have a monitor that runs every minute).

When I try to switch them polling from 1 per second to once every 60 seconds, it will, instead, take the increment value and divide it by 60 and create an rate per second.

Anyone have an idea of how to expose a JMX value via Netflix Servo package to do a 60s metric instead? There's CounterToRateMetricTransform but there are no examples on how to convert a Counter metric to a Rate.

Answer (score 0):

StepCounter is an individual metric, but CounterToRateMetricTransform is applied to a MetricObserver, and returns a new observer that observes all counters transformed as rates

e.g. to create an observer that observes counters as rates and add it to a pollrunnable task

```
MetricObserver observer = new CloudWatchMetricObserver(...) // existing observer
MetricObserver transformedObserver = new CounterToRateMetricTransform(observer, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
PollRunnable task = new PollRunnable(..., Immutable.listOf(transformedObserver));
```

Unfortunately this transform also returns a rate per second (see CounterToRateMetricTransform.computeRate)

There's no way to get a per minute rate through the existing library as far as I can see, you'd need to either implement your own metric (like StepCounter) or your own transform on an observer (like CounterToRateMetricTransform) depending on your use case.

The best approach is probably just to take the per second rate and multiply it by 60 in your monitoring system rather than changing the reporting